# Create or attach Byobu default windows

Tags: tmux, byobu

I run Byobu (backed by Tmux) on a remote machine. I have a basic window layout which is what I generally want, and I've configured Byobu to launch at login so when I `ssh` to the remote machine I resume my session and when I want to leave I <kbd>F6</kbd> to detach and disconnect. This works well.

My problem is when I reboot the machine all my Byobu windows are erased. I'm not trying (yet?) to resume exactly where I left off, but just getting all the windows with their names would be a big help.

I can use `.byobu/window.tmux` to have a window layout that's executed when I connect. But I've tried this

```
new-session 'remote';
new-window -n irc;
new-window -n code;
new-window -n logs;
```

and that causes Byobu to create a new session each time I connect, so I can't resume anymore.

Then I tried adding the `-A` flag to attach:

```
new-session -A 'remote';
new-window -n irc;
new-window -n code;
new-window -n logs;
```

This goes back to resuming the old session, but now every time I connect I get an *additional* three windows added to the windows I had before.

Here's pseudo-code for what I want:

```
if session_exists('remote') {
  attach('remote');
} else {
  new-session 'remote';
  new-window -n irc;
  new-window -n code;
  new-window -n logs;
}
```

Can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I found this article where the guy explains how to create one main, unattached session and then create a shared session from that one.
This results in the behavior you're aiming for, I believe.
Check out this article:
[byobu-tmux tabbed windows](https://timothybasanov.com/2016/04/24/byobu-tmux-tabbed-terminal-support.html)

Comment: Thanks! That looks really promising. I can't confirm because I gave up on Byobu and switched to plain Tmux, configured to copy basic Byobu behavior.